# How do I convert distance covered from meters to kilometers, in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I am developing a game in Unity where I have to find a distance in kilometers, to find a passenger's fare based on  the covered distance.

This is what I have tried:

```
private Vector3 previousPosition; 
public float cumulatedDistance;

void Awake()
{
    // initialize to the current position
    previousPosition = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    cumulatedDistance += (transform.position - previousPosition).magnitude;
    previousPosition = transform.position;
}
```

How can I determine the distance covered, and convert it to kilometers?

Comment: What's the base unit of your game?

Comment: @Sean Base unit is Meter.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use the intended scale, one unit should be equivalent to one metre. In turn, you can work out kilometres travelled as `[units_travelled] / 1000`.

Your on the right track with how you implement tracking your distance. You *could* use `Vector3.Distance()` to work out the distance between each change in position, but if you look at the API, you will note that it reads *Vector3.Distance(a,b) is the same as (a-b).magnitude.* In other words, your already doing it. Using `Vector3.Distance()` might be more convenient, if you have trouble remembering the maths behind it and would rather directly reference it as *distance*, but there is no reason to use one over the other for functionality.

---

```
///<summary>How many game units make up a metre?</summary>
public float unitConversion = 1.0f;
///<summary>How much should be paid, per kilometre?</summary>
public float kiloMetreCost = 3.50f;
///<summary>Float to hold record of distance travelled</summary>
private float cumulatedDistance = 0.0f;
///<summary>Holds record of the last position</summary>
private Vector3 lastPosition;

public void Awake()
{
    lastPosition = transform.position;
}

public void Update()
{
    cumulatedDistance += ((transform.position - previous position).magnitude);
}

///<summary>Returns the current distance travelled, in metres.</summary>
public float GetDistanceInMetres()
{
    // use unit conversion to determine total metres
    return (cumulatedDistance / unitConversion);
}

///<summary>Returns the current cumulated distance, in kilometres.</summary>
public float GetDistanceInKiloMetres()
{
    // use distance conversion to determine total kilometres
    return (GetDistanceInMetres() / 1000.0f);
}

///<summary>Returns the total cost, based off cumulated distance.</summary>
public float GetTotalCost()
{
    // Use simple multiplication to determine final cost.
    return (kiloMetreCost * GetDistanceInKiloMetres());
}
```

---

The above script will keep track of its cumulated distance, and allow you to retrieve total distances. I included metres *and* kilometres, and as you mentioned a price, a total cost.

You can change 'unitConversion', if you do not use the standard unit scales. If you set your game up so that one unit equates to one centimetre, you would have `unitConversion = 100.0f`. If you set your game up so that one unit equates to eight metres, you would have `unitConversion = 7.0f`.

It is important to note that we retain `float` format to allow greater accuracy. If you need to work in integer values, remember that when you convert them to `int`, they will lose their decimal places.